# DLP in a Cyclic group

Tags: cryptography

Let $q$ be a prime. $G$ is a cyclic group of order $q^2$. Show that for solving the DLP in $G$ it's enough to solve two distinct DLPs in two groups of order $q$.

---

We are looking for an $x$ such that $\alpha^x=\beta$ in this group $G$.

By the CRT $G \cong C_q \times C_q$ alright? So taking the CRT-isomorphism yields

$\phi(\alpha^x)=(\alpha^x \mod q, \alpha^x \mod q)\overset{!}{=} (\beta \mod q,\beta \mod q)=\phi(\beta)$

So we have to solve $\alpha^x=\beta$ in $C_q$ now? But is this correct? I doubt that because in the exercise they want two distinct DLPs ???

Comment: This is pretty hard to read because of the acronyms and the undefined function $\phi$.  But $G\equiv C_q \times C_q$ is definitely not true; the Chinese Remainder Theorem only applies to two relatively prime integers.

Comment: Well $\Phi$ is the well-known CRT isomorphism. Okay you are right this is not true. But how does this exercise work then?

Answer (score 0):

Write $x=x_1+x_2q$. Solve $a^{x_1} = b \bmod{q}$ to find $x_1$. 
Let $a^q \bmod{q} = c$, $b a^{-x_1} \bmod{q}=d$. 
Find $x_2$ by solving $c^{x_2} = d \bmod{q}$.